# how to use mongo db.server.js in loopback

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I want to use something like this 
(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the mongo connection from the datasource in your model. Like so:

```
Model.getDatasource().connector.connect((err, db) => {
  const collection = db.getCollection("Model");
  collection.save({
    "_id": "echoFunction",
    "value": new Model.getDatasource().Code("function(x) { return x; }")
  });
});
```